# Docker-compose mounted file system operation not permitted for volume

Tags: permissions, mount, mysql, docker, container

I am experiencing a problem with docker-compose, its mounting a volume in a folder on a mounted hard drive. I have seen lots of solutions out there and honestly tried them all.

I changed the permissions to the user that I am using, to root, to docker, within their respective groups. Nothing

Writing operations work fine, I can write a file through python I am not restricted, but when I run docker compose to make an sql db it gives me this:

> ERROR: for mysql_db  Cannot start service mysql_db: error while
> creating mount source path '/db-path-mount': chown
> /db-path-mount/db-volume-folder/db-one: operation not permitted
>
> ERROR: for mysql_db  Cannot start service mysql_db: error while
> creating mount source path '/db-path-mount': chown
> /db-path-mount/db-volume-folder/db-one: operation not permitted ERROR:
> Encountered errors while bringing up the project.

Out there seems that the troubleshooting is scarce, I tried docker-compose up -d and sudo docker-compose up -d, nothing really changes.

```
drwxr-xr-x 3 myUser docker 4028276 Jul 26 04:47 db-volume-folder/
```

and my mount point (etc/fstab):

```
UUID=MY_UUID /home/user/my_mount_point    auto uid=1001,gid=122,umask=022,defaults 0 1

(gid=122 is docker)
(uid=1001 is user)
```

**I am using ubuntu 20 server**

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  my_sql_db:
    container_name: my_sql_db
    user: root
    image: mysql/mysql-server:latest
    ports:
      - "1533:3306"
    env_file:
      - secrets/sqlserver.env
      - secrets/sqlpassword.env
    volumes:
      - ./db-path-mount/db-volume-folder/db-one:/var/lib/mysql
```

Comment: Would you mind sharing your `docker-compose.yml` (remember to redact any passwords etc). Also, is the mount point defined in your `/etc/fstab`?

Comment: Sure, I posted it, yes the mountpoint is in fstab

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things in your setup that I would do differently, and I'll try to outline this in my answer. I can't guarantee it will work, but it's how I have my containers set up, so hopefully it can help.

First, I wouldn't mount my data disk with `uid` and `gid` attributes. I would mount with default attributes, like this:

```
UUID=MY_UUID /home/user/my_mount_point    auto umask=022,defaults 0 1
```

(From this point on, I will use `/home/user/my_mount_point` as a reference from where your disk is mounted.)

Secondly, I don't understand your volume reference in the `docker-compose.yml`. I would have it like this:

```
    volumes:
      - /home/user/my_mount_point/db-volume-folder/db-one:/var/lib/mysql
```

Note that I would always use an absolute path in the `docker-compose.yml`.

Also, the ownership should match those of the container running, so the folder `db-one` should be owned by root.

```
myUser@ubuntu:~/my_mount_point/db-volume-folder$

drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4028276 Jul 26 04:47 db-one
```

Note that the folder name `db-one` should match the *last folder* on the *left side* in the volume mount path - this is the folder where the permissions matter.

Finally, as you have noted, docker-compose also supports that you specify which user the container should run as. So I believe you could change the user, and then change the ownership accordingly.

So if you change the user like this:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  my_sql_db:
    container_name: my_sql_db
    user: myUser
```

And then the folder permissions to match:

```
myUser@ubuntu:~/my_mount_point/db-volume-folder$

drwxr-xr-x 3 myUser myUser 4028276 Jul 26 04:47 db-one
```

I hope some of these instructions will work for you - please let us know if it does.

EDIT:

I just tested the MySql container with the following docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.7"

services:

  my_sql_db:
    container_name: my_sql_db
    user: root
    image: mysql/mysql-server:latest
    ports:
      - "1533:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: topsecret
      MYSQL_USER: mysqluser
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: mysqlpassword
    volumes:
      - /mnt/zfs/docker-data/mysql-test/db-one:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
```

This is the contents of the folder `/mnt/zfs/docker-data/mysql-test`:

```
/mnt/zfs/docker-data/mysql-test$ ls -la
total 7
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root   4 Aug  1 22:02 .
drwxr-xr-x 22 root root  22 Aug  1 21:47 ..
drwxr-xr-x  6   27 sudo  30 Aug  1 21:59 db-one
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 374 Aug  1 21:58 docker-compose.yml
```

In this way, the container comes up successfully. It appears the container itself changes ownership to `27:sudo` (I guess these are default values).

If I change the user in `docker-compose.yml` to `myuser:myuser` and also change permissions on the folder `db-one` to `myuser:myuser`, I get this error when trying to start the container:

```
ERROR: for my_sql_db  Cannot start service my_sql_db: unable to find user myuser: no matching entries in passwd file
```

So it seems the problem is between matching users, and not filesystem ownership. And if you get another error, its probably something else than filesystem ownership - see my link in comments.

Comment: Creating my_db ... error

ERROR: for my_db  Cannot start service my_db: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: process_linux.go:385: applying cgroup configuration for process caused: no cgroup mount found in mountinfo: unknown

ERROR: for my_db  Cannot start service my_db: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: process_linux.go:385: applying cgroup configuration for process caused: no cgroup mount found in mountinfo: unknown
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.

Comment: Did everything ^^ what I get

Comment: Could you edit your question with the new config files, and also be sure to have the correct volume paths - if not I can't help troubleshooting.

Comment: [This post on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66004068/how-to-resolve-no-cgroup-mount-found-in-mountinfo-unknown-error) has suggestions to solve the new error you are getting - could you look into this? Thanks.

Comment: It seems maybe there is a problem with your docker installation, or systemd cgroup configuration.

Comment: Nope and nope, tried throughout what's in that thread and I am getting the same exact error.

I reinstalled docker twice, before applying the first suggestion (your edit), and trying what's in the thread, same error (OCI error)

Comment: Strange. For reference, I've personally been using [MariaDB from Linuxserver.io](https://hub.docker.com/r/linuxserver/mariadb) without issue, if that's an option for you maybe give it a spin?